# In Odoo,what's the difference between the http and https when it comes to writing the controllers?There is an error

Tags: python, https, odoo, werkzeug

I have wirtten a controllers in an Odoo module.There is no problem using postman to test the interface in the debug environment based on **http**.However,there is some problem using postman to test the interface in the production environment based on **https**.

Python version 2.7.12

Odoo version 10.0

werkzeug version 0.11.11

Here is my code.Please help me,thank you.

### Production environment and the protocol is https.

**controllers.py**

```py
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from odoo.http import Controller
from odoo.http import route
from odoo.http import request

class PhotoPruner(Controller):
    @route('/<string:type>/photo/size/<int:record_id>', type='http', auth='none', methods=['GET'], csrf=False)
    def get_info(self, **kwargs):
        type = kwargs.get('type')
        record_id = kwargs.get('record_id')
        return 'ok'
```

**postman test**
[image: The result of postman test]

**log error info**
[image: The picture of log error]

### Debug environment and the protocol is http

There is no problem.

I receive the 'ok' when I get the http://127.0.0.1/task/photo/size/146

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Odoo routing supports two type of requests, `http` and `json`. you are getting error on production probably because of using `https` which is a type not even supported. When you are using web servers `nginx` or `apache` in front of your Odoo application and reverse proxy to Odoo application, you are probably using `http` protocol between webserver and application communication. Check the `proxy_pass` of your nginx configuration, probably the reverse proxy is `http://127.0.0.1:8069` (if you are nginx, or respective apache virtual host configuration line).

For more information about Odoo web controllers, please refer to the official [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/http.html#routing) of Odoo, it is specifically mentioned that request type can be `http` or `json`.

Comment: You are right!Our server is ```Nginx``` and the reverse proxy is ```http://127.0.0.1:8069```.Does this mean that in an production environment we can only define our controllers interface in a ```type='json'``` manner?

Comment: No not necessarily, we have to use `http` or `json` respectively based on the request type the controller will process. For example, if it is a `xhr` request with `json` body, you can use `json`. If it will be a normal request you can use `http` type. doesn't have to be different in production or development environment. HTTPS should be enforced by the web server for secure environment in production.